# Run docker process on foreground

Tags: docker, ssh, process, dockerfile, docker-container

I have a container running ssh and a java program.
[This is a screen shot of a terminal window showing it running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zem6n.png)

When I connect to the container via SSH my java program is running on background. I want to bring it to foreground.

What I want to do is:
When I connect via SSH I want to "docker attach" but from the inside the container using ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bring service to foreground you need to run that service in a way that allows you to easily get its stdout, stderr and stdin connected to other session (e.g. run it in `tmux` or `screen`). Docker doesn't provide such facility.

To see output of your service you can use `docker logs`. See [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/) for more detailed information. If you need to interact with service you can use `docker attach` at any time when container is running and that will show output (stdout, stderr) and also allow you to make input (stdin) from your terminal where you ran `docker attach`. See documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/).

When you SSH in container you're essentially creating a new session (like when you connect to server running a daemon).